Passing derived class to a method
newbie here, trying to figure out best way to achieve the following:
Have a base class:
public class MessageBaseDto
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
}

And 2 derived classes:
public class DataMessageBaseDto:MessageBaseDto
{
    public string AssetType { get; set; }
    public long StartDate { get; set; }
    public long EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class CalculationMessageBaseDto:MessageBaseDto
{
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCacheReady { get; set; }
    public string MetricName { get; set; }
    public int MetricVersion { get; set; }
}

And also the class that use the derived classes as properties:
public class CommandServiceBusMessage<T> where T : MessageBaseDto
{ 
    [JsonPropertyName("command")]
    public CommandType Command { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("payload")]
    public T Payload { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("correlationId")]
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

Also have a method that needs to accept any messages with properties that derive from the base MessageBaseDto type:
Task SendMessageAsync(CommandServiceBusMessage<MessageBaseDto> msg, string sendToDestinationTopic);

I am trying to work out if this can be achieved in the way I started? At the moment, when I call the method I get an error:
var messageToSend = new CommandServiceBusMessage<CalculationMessageBaseDto>();
messageToSend.Command = CommandType.CalculateAlgorithm;
messageToSend.CorrelationId = serviceBusMessage.CorrelationId;
messageToSend.Payload = new CalculationMessageBaseDto();

await SendMessageAsync(messageToSend, _senderCalcTopicName);

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DeBeers.Analytics.Orchestration.Domain.Dtos.CommandServiceBusMessage<DeBeers.Analytics.Orchestration.Domain.Dtos.CalculationMessageBaseDto>' to 'DeBeers.Analytics.Orchestration.Domain.Dtos.CommandServiceBusMessage<DeBeers.Analytics.Orchestration.Domain.Dtos.MessageBaseDto>' DeBeers.Analytics.Orchestration.Service C:\Users\boguss\source\repos\analytics-orchestration-service\DeBeers.Analytics.Orchestration.Service\Services\ServiceBusTopicSubscription.cs    81  Active

I think you're better off defining 2 payloads; and making one optional; or a "collection" of payloads; even if you only have one for the time being. This is one of those sanity things.

And add a common "interface" to pass around. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface

I think you don't need to use generics. Try public class  CommandServiceBusMessage
{
[JsonPropertyName("command")]
public CommandType Command { get; set; }
[JsonPropertyName("payload")]
public MessageBaseDto Payload { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("correlationId")]
public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

}

To fix your issue, you need to change the definition of your function "SendMessageAsync". Here is the proper definition you should use:
public async Task SendMessageAsync<T>(CommandServiceBusMessage<T> msg, string sendToDestinationTopic) 
    where T: MessageBaseDto 
{
    // Do something here
}

Hope that helps!
Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zKVBLV
